# Grails JAR file in lib directory not found

Tags: java, grails, jar

I have a Java class which is located in `src/java` that references classes from an external JAR. I copied the JAR file to the `lib` directory. When I go to run the app using `grails run-app` I get an error that it can't find the imported class.

What is the correct location to put JARs for a Grails project? Is there some special command to get Grails to recognize the newly added JAR files?

I am running Grails 2.0.0 with Java 1.6.0_29 on OS X.

**Follow-up:** The JARs are question are from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). More specifically:

```
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
```

The class files in them are compiled to Java 1.3, which shouldn't be a problem.

```
~/temp/org/apache/http $ file HttpResponse.class 
HttpResponse.class: compiled Java class data, version 47.0 (Java 1.3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to add jar's is by adding it to your "BuildConfig.groovy". You can specify if it is needed at compile time, runtime etc. For example:

```
dependencies {        
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2' 
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2' 
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
}
```

Please note, you may also need to uncomment the mavenCentral() line in your Buildconfig.groovy in order for the dependencies to get resolved.

See "Dependency Resolution" section [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html).

Comment: Starting with Grails 2.0.0, mavenCentral() is uncommented by default :)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Even though I put my jar in project lib folder it is not loading at all:-( What if I want to add my own jar needs to be added which is not in maven central?

Comment: After a couple hours of wrestling with this (at least), your answer and especially the link to the docs saved me.  +1, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Very odd, I ran `grails clean` and then `grails run-app` and it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: I still have the problem... using grails 2.0.3

Comment: have you added the jar to the build path?

Answer (score 6):

When you add or remove jar files in `lib` you need to run

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

in order to get Grails to notice the changes.