# Adding custom library to Grails project

Tags: grails

I got issue with custom library that I am trying to add to my Grails project. 
I have tagsoup-1.2.jar library that I put into "lib" folder under Grails project. 
However when I am running my project I am getting following error:

> @ line 135, column 24.
>           def tagsoupParser = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()
>                             ^ 1 error

Now I added library to class path via "Build Path" option in Eclipse, but that didn't help.

Please can anyone tell me where to put library? and/or why I get error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer via following link: [Grails JAR file in lib directory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784720/grails-jar-file-in-lib-directory-not-found)

I needed to clean project via:

> grails clean

Once that was done, I just run it again and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, I ran grails clean. That still didn't work. I then did refresh dependencies and that fixed. it.